# Python: Cleanest Way to Run Cascading Functions if Previous Function Returned None

Tags: python, function, dictionary, if-statement

Essentially, I have a 3 separate functions. I want to run `geopy_parse` first, and if it returns `None`, then I'll run `libpostal_parse`, and if that returns `None`, I'll finally run the last function `google_maps_parse`. The final return of the function should be the result of the last sub-function that was run. I have created a function that accomplishes this, but I would like to rewrite it in a cleaner more pythonic way.

Code Example:

```
def parse_address(address_str):
    # if no address string provided, return None result
    if not address_str:
        return (None, None, None)
    
    # execute geopy parser
    res = geopy_parse(address_str)
    
    if not res:
        res = libpostal_parse(address_str)
    if not res:
        res = google_maps_parse(address_str)
    
    return {
        'nation': res['country'],
        'state': res['state'],
        'city': res['city'] or res['town'] or res['county']
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good hint to how this can be simplified is to identify that you've got repeated code. You can also make use of the fact that python supports first-class functions (i.e. that they can be passed as values/arguments elsewhere).

**Edit** I've just seen your change. One of the benefits of this method as opposed to a bunch of if-statements is that it scales quite easily if you want to add more parsers.

```
def parse_address(address_str):
    # if no address string provided, return None result
    if not address_str:
        return (None, None, None)
    
    func_list = [geopy_parse, libpostal_parse, google_maps_parse]

    for func in func_list:
        res = func(address_str)

        # The return statement immediately breaks out of the loop
        # I.e. if the first func returns a non-None value, the others don't get executed
        if res is not None:
            return {
                'nation': res['country'],
                'state': res['state'],
                'city': res['city'] or res['town'] or res['county']
            }
    else:
        # Handles the situation where all of your parsers return None
        return (None, None, None)
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `None` is the only possible falsy output of your function, you can just treat them as boolean-ish and use `or` to fallback e.g.

```py
res = geopy_parse(address_str) or libpostal_parse(address_str) or google_maps_parse(address_str)
```

will return the first non-falsy result.

You could also use `next()` in order to have more flexibility, but that's a bit more complicated as you have to filter out the falsy values before feeding the iterable to next e.g.

```py
res = next(filter(None, (
    fn(address_str)
    for fn in [geopy_parse, libpostal_parse, google_maps_parse]
)), None)
```

`filter(None, iterable)` is equivalent to but more efficient than `filter(lambda a: a, iterable)`, it will remove all falsy items from the iterable (lazily).

So this takes functions as inputs, tries applying each one to the input, only keeps the truthy result, then returns the first such (that's what `next()` does).

Because it only uses lazy constructs (generators and filters), it only evaluates a function if none of the previous ones was suitable.